# Why does the below code not print anything?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

While I write `switch(true)` it produces the correct result, otherwise it does not produce any result. Why?

```
let age=18;

switch(age){
    
case age>18:

    console.log("you can vote");

    break;

    case age<18:

    console.log("you cannnot vote");

    break;
}
```

Comment: Because that's simply not how switch works. You have to match the value, you're comparing number to booleans. Read a basic tutorial or reference, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch.

Comment: Because the value you're testing is `age` (`18`), and there is no `case` label that matches it. Your `case age>18:` label is functionally the same as `case false:` (since `age` is `18`). While you *could* use `switch (true)` and then `case age > 18:` (because unusually, in JavaScript case labels are expressions and they're tested against the switch value in source code order), you're really better off with `if`/`else if`/`else`.

Answer (score 0):

The switch expression is a condition that can only work with equality `==` that's why it doesn't work in your case. you should use If-chains like this:

```js
let age = 18;

if(age > 18) 
{
    console.log("you can vote");
}

else if(age < 18) 
{
    console.log("you can not vote");
}
```

The above code is the common solution for checking those types of conditions.